# How to properly use MaterialUI icons in CoreUI React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, core-ui

I need to use Material UI icons in a React dashboard template of CoreUI, for that, i installed `@mui/material` and `@mui/icons-material` with:

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

And

```
npm install @mui/icons-material
```

This is my **package.json** now:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@coreui/chartjs": "^3.0.0",
    "@coreui/coreui": "^4.2.1",
    "@coreui/icons": "^2.1.0",
    "@coreui/icons-react": "^2.1.0",
    "@coreui/react": "^4.4.0",
    "@coreui/react-chartjs": "^2.1.0",
    "@coreui/utils": "^1.3.1",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.6",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.6"
//...
}
```

Then in the `src/_nav.js` file, there where should i import the icon and use it. So i tried this code below:

```
import React from 'react'
import CIcon from '@coreui/icons-react'
import { CNavItem } from '@coreui/react'
import PeopleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/People'

const _nav = [
  {
    component: CNavItem,
    name: 'Users',
    to: '/theme/colors',
    icon: <CIcon icon={PeopleIcon} customClassName="nav-icon" />,
  },
]
export default _nav
```

Now the NPM in terminal shows `Compiled successfully!` but i'm getting a blank page with this error in console.dev:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '@emotion/react'

Comment: Did you try deleting the `node_modules` folder and running `npm install` again?

Comment: i fixed it by restarting the npm compilator after installing material ui biblio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, it's recommanded that you restart your npm terminal after installing new package.

Secondly, you can't implement materialUI icon in the same way you use CoreUi icons.
You have to use `icon: <PeopleIcon />,` instead of `icon: <CIcon icon={PeopleIcon} customClassName="nav-icon" />,`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react'
import CIcon from '@coreui/icons-react'
import { CNavItem } from '@coreui/react'
import PeopleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/People'

const _nav = [
  {
    component: CNavItem,
    name: 'Users',
    to: '/theme/colors',
    icon: <PeopleIcon />,
  },
]
export default _nav
```

Comment: sorry, `icon: <PeopleIcon />,` didn't fix it, i'm still getting the same error above.